# How to grab all metadata from any image?

Tags: swift

I have been searching google and could not find a solution for my problem. I have some code that grabs metadata from images the user picks from the image picker. The problem is that my code doesn't grab ALL metadata from HEIC and RAW images. I set up some print statements to find out which data my code doesn't grab from HEIC.

Manufacturer not found

Camera model not found

Camera software not found

Aperture not found

Focal length not found

ISO not found

Shutter speed not found

```
//And this is my metadata extracting code block

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    let image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage
    let url = info[.imageURL]
    let optionalImageData = try? Data(contentsOf: url as! URL)
    guard let imageData = optionalImageData else { return }
    let source: CGImageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(imageData as CFData, nil)!
    let metadata = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(source, 0, nil) as? [AnyHashable: Any]

    print(metadata!)

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that you have not obtained user permission to access the photos library. You are allowed to present the picker even so, but the information that you can receive in response is very limited. If you have user permission, you can receive the image as a PHAsset and you can get the desired metadata from the photos library.

Comment: I have photo library usage permission, and have explicitly requested it after reading your answer, but the problem persists. There is some problem with HEIC while jpg images work perfectly.

Comment: Well, you _say_ that, but I don't see you _doing_ it. Your code doesn't do what I suggested. It doesn't return to the photo library with the PHAsset and it doesn't ask the photo library for the metadata.